# How can I get CSS image-set (srcset) from Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, background-image, image-size, srcset

I would like to implement a css background image with image-set, like:

```
background-image: 
    image-set(
      url(examples/images/image-384.jpg) 1x,
      url(examples/images/image-768.jpg) 2x,
    );
```

Is there a way to get something like this from Wordpress? Like

```
wp_get_attachment_image_srcset();
```

for normale images.